# How do I subset a data frame by row names that do not meet a condition?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that consists of names and dates. I wish to subset the data frame by names that do not appear in 3 consecutive years. Here is my data frame:

`data <- data.frame( Name = c("Dex","Dex","Rex","Rex","Rex","Lex","Lex",
"Nex","Nex","Nex"), Year = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002 ))`

`Name   Year
 Dex    2000
 Dex    2001
 Rex    2000
 Rex    2001
 Rex    2002
 Lex    2001
 Lex    2002
 Nex    2000
 Nex    2001
 Nex    2002`

This is the desired output:

`Name   Year
 Dex    2000
 Dex    2001
 Lex    2001
 Lex    2002`

Is there a way to subset data according to conditions that are not met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example, the 'Year' for all unique 'Name' are consecutive.  So, an easier option would be to group by 'Name' and `filter` if the number of distinct 'Year' is less than 3 or the number of rows (`n()`) is less than 3

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(Name) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(Year) < 3)
   #or the number of rows
   # filter(n() < 3)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   Name [2]
#  Name   Year
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 Dex    2000
#2 Dex    2001
#3 Lex    2001
#4 Lex    2002
```

---

As a general case, after grouping by 'Name', we get the `diff`erence of adjacent 'Year', check if it is equal to 1 i.e. 1 year difference, use that in run-length-encoding (`rle`) to find the `max`imum length of sequence of consecutive 'year' is less than 3 to `filter` those 'Name' groups

```
data %>%
   group_by(Name) %>% 
   filter(with(rle(c(TRUE, diff(Year)) == 1), max(lengths[values])) < 3)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   Name [2]
#  Name   Year
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 Dex    2000
#2 Dex    2001
#3 Lex    2001
#4 Lex    2002
```

Comment: Thank you very much, akrun! I had been playing around with the dplyr package, but I couldn't figure out how to generate a logical comparison using the filter function.